# Why do some users and not others get ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into primary key

Tags: oracle, nextval, ora-01400

EDIT:  I have replaced the generic SQL with the actual SQL.

I know how to fix it.  I am just wondering why it worked on some developer machines and not others.

```
CREATE TABLE OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION ("OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATIONID" NUMBER, "OUTPUTDEFNTYPE" NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL, "OUTPUTDEFNID" NUMBER NOT NULL, "PROJECTVIEWID" NUMBER, "SYSTEMUSERID" NUMBER, "VISIBLE" NUMBER(3,0));
ALTER TABLE OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION ADD CONSTRAINT OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION_P PRIMARY KEY (OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATIONID) ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION ADD CONSTRAINT OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION_PROJECT FOREIGN KEY (PROJECTVIEWID) REFERENCES PROJECTVIEW (PROJECTVIEWID) ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION ADD CONSTRAINT OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION_USER FOREIGN KEY (SYSTEMUSERID) REFERENCES SYSTEMUSER (SYSTEMUSERID) ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION UNIQUE (OUTPUTDEFNTYPE, OUTPUTDEFNID, SYSTEMUSERID, PROJECTVIEWID);
CREATE SEQUENCE "OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION_SEQ" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 1.00000000000000E+27 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE;

INSERT INTO OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION (OUTPUTDEFNTYPE, OUTPUTDEFNID, SYSTEMUSERID, PROJECTVIEWID, VISIBLE) 
SELECT 0, KPIDEFNID, SYSTEMUSERID, PROJECTVIEWID, VISIBLE FROM KPIDEFN, SYSTEMUSER, PROJECTVIEW, DUAL WHERE ACTIVE = 1 AND SYSTEMUSERID <> 1 AND STATUSID IN (1,4);
```

My fix is

```
INSERT INTO OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION (OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATIONID, OUTPUTDEFNTYPE, OUTPUTDEFNID, SYSTEMUSERID, PROJECTVIEWID, VISIBLE) 
SELECT OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 0, KPIDEFNID, SYSTEMUSERID, PROJECTVIEWID, VISIBLE FROM KPIDEFN, SYSTEMUSER, PROJECTVIEW, DUAL WHERE ACTIVE = 1 AND SYSTEMUSERID <> 1 AND STATUSID IN (1,4);
```

But why wasn't it necessary on all developer machines?  They all have their own schema, but my script created this table for them all.

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DEVF22FMT"."OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION"."OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATIONID")
```

Comment: Your query will not work on any Oracle RDBMS as you have a `SELECT` statement without a `FROM` clause. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e5812fb04b1824081cfb7b119740d0e8)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the `CREATE SEQUENCE` and `CREATE TABLE` and (any relevant) `CREATE TRIGGER` statements used on the different machines and the Oracle version of those machines. Without a way to replicate the issue we are just guessing.

Comment: Sorry @MT0 that was not clear - edited to real SQL

Answer (score 1):

The same table behaves the same way, so - if all of them (developers) used the same `INSERT` statement, connected to the same database (user), they'd get the **same** result - either success or a failure.

---

However, if they have their own schemas, then it depends on the way they created target tables.

Behaviour you described could be result of

- identity column (12c onwards)
- database trigger

which then "automatically", in the *background*, populate that `NOT NULL` column.

Comment: I have edited the question to give the actual SQL including the CREATE statement

Comment: We can't execute it; your INSERT references 3 additional tables (FROM KPIDEFN, SYSTEMUSER, PROJECTVIEW) so ... who knows what's their contents? Apparently, some of your users have NULLs in some column(s). Also, try to use JOINs instead of comma-separated list of tables in FROM clause. Leave WHERE for *filtering* data (applying certain conditions).

Comment: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DEVF22FMT"."OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATION"."OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATIONID")

It is definitely the identity column on this table at fault

Comment: There's no evidence (based on code you posted) that column OUTPUTDEFNACTIVATIONID is an identity column. It is a primary key column, but not an identity column. Therefore, you must specify its value during INSERT.